# Play Framework routing path lookup

Tags: playframework, routes

Is it possible to print out the path of a incomming request in Play Framework?

If the user types **example.com/thisrandomstring** in the browser, but i have not specified:

```
//If this is NOT in my "routes" file
POST /thisrandomstring controllers.Application.doSomething()
```

Is there still a way for me to "system.out.print" that someone tried to type "/thisrandomstring" ?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easist way is probably that you define a catch all route in the end of your routes file. Something like:

```
GET     /*path      controllers.HomeController.catchAll(path: String)
```

And simply log whatever you want in your controller. For example:

```
public Result catchAll(final String path) {
    Logger.warn("url: " + path);
    return notFound();
}
```